# Proof verification: Show that it is possible to select $\sqrt{n}$ points from n points so that the points don't form an equilateral triangle.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I just came across this problem and was unsure if my proof was correct, since it seemed to good to be true. It goes as follows:

> Show that it is possible to select $\sqrt{n}$ points from $n$ points in the $2D$ Plane so that the points don't form an equilateral triangle.

First, choose any two points. Call these $A$ and $B$ and the distance between them $d_1$. Consider a circle with center $B$ and radius $d_1$. For the next-to-be selected point ($C$) to form an equilateral triangle with A and B, it needs to lie on the aforementioned circle. Furthermore, there are only two such points, corresponding to to the points which allow the triangle to have an angle of 60 degrees. So, we can select a total of $2$($A$ and $B$) + $(n-4)$ = $n-2$ points that do not form equilateral triangles. Then we can maybe consider $n= 1, 2, 3, 4$ individually and use this argument for $n\geq 5$.

As I said, this looks too good to be true, and my brain for some reason is having a hard time in coming up with counterexamples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really correct. It is true that there are $n-4$ points that does not form an equilateral triangle **with $A$ and $B$**, but for **themselves**, three of them can form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't make sense to me. Yes by considering A and B only, we exclude at most 2 points. But that doesn't mean that we can take all of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your solution doesn't make sense to me. Yes by considering A and B only, we exclude at most 2 points. But that doesn't mean that we can take all of the rest of the points. We still have to see what points the other pairs might exclude.

---

OP actually has all of the information that is required. The crux is indeed "Every pair of points excludes at most 2 other points."

As a rough guide, if we have chosen $< \sqrt{n} $ points, we will exclude at most $< { \sqrt{n} \choose 2 } \times 2 = n^2 - \sqrt{n}$ other points, and so there **should** be a point leftover for us to choose.

To complete this solution, justify the above "should". I suggest letting $ n = m^2 + k$, and see what happens if when we have chosen $m-1$ points.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your hint! I revised the proof as follows, can you tell me if it looks good?

Thanks for your hint! I revised the proof as follows, can you tell me if it looks good?
When we choose 2 points, we exclude $2 \cdot {2 \choose 2}$ points. Similarly, if we choose $l$ points, we exclude $2 \cdot {l \choose 2}$ points. So, we need $l + 2 \cdot {l \choose 2} \leq n$. And the largest value for $l$ that does this is $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @Alp Essentially yes, like I said. But phrasing is key here, so I'd recommend for you to write it up for clarity.